# ListView FlyoutMenu

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Как правильно реализовать вызов контекстного меню на Item в ListView. И как реализовать событие клика на кнопке удалить в этом меню для удаления Item из ListView.

Решено:

```html
<ListView.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                                            <ListViewItemPresenter>
                                                                <ListViewItemPresenter.ContextFlyout>
                                                                    <MenuFlyout>
                                                                        <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Удалить" Click="DeleteTrack_Click" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                                                                    </MenuFlyout>
                                                                </ListViewItemPresenter.ContextFlyout>
                                                            </ListViewItemPresenter>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ListView.Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

У `ListView` есть свойство `SelectedItem`. Это как раз выбранный элемент.

Comment: Дело в том, что мой ListView не подразумевает выбора элемента. Поэтому SelectedItem будет возвращать null. И RightTap не будет выбирать элемент.

Comment: Тогда можно вынести обработку события в DataTemplate и там через Behaviors получать DataContext элемента на котором произошло событие.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста,  как это сделать правильно.

Comment: Для MVVM примерно так. Хотя это и не то, о чем я говорил, но должно работать.
<MenuFlyoutItem Text="Искать в интернете"
    Command="{Нужная команда}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>